# Exporting Comments from Microsoft Word with brief context details

Tags: microsoft-word, comments

I want to export Comments from a Microsoft Word file with some context provided of what is being commented on. [This guide](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/print-list-comments-microsoft-word/) shows me how to export Comments but they are meaningless without having details of *what is being commented on*.

[image: Comments without context]

Ideally I am looking for an output similar to the doctored image below, where the left side shows the texts highlighted in Microsoft Word to capture what they are being commented on:

[image]

Where the input document is:

[image]

Comment: There is nothing native in Word to do this. You, or someone, will have to write an application in vba to do it.

Comment: My gutfeel was telling me this as I was writing up this post. Wouldn't mind some directions from someone re VBA snippets that I can use.

Comment: Please check whether these threads are helpful. "[Export Comments with referred text and line numbers from Word to Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/export-comments-with-referred-text-and-line-numbers-from-word-to-excel.1120281/)","[Export comments and corresponding text from MS Word to Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/export-comments-and-corresponding-text-from-ms-word-to-excel.795267/page-3#posts)".